# RegionPlot: how to plot legend on graphic, but not outside

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, legending

For the `RegionPlot` command, the code `PlotLegends -> {Style[,],Style[,]}` generates plot legend outside the graphic. But I need to generate the legend inside the graphic, precisely, on the domain $y < f(x)$ there must be corresponding legend.

How to do that?

For concreteness, I want the following (see picture).[image]

Each of legends is located inside the corresponding domain. The code corresponding to picture is

```
RegionPlot[{y > -6 - 3/2*x, y > -12 + x/4}, {x, -20, 10}, {y, -20, 
  20}, PlotLegends -> {Style["Lifetime", FontSize -> 20], 
   Style["Angular approximation", FontSize -> 20]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Subscript[Log, 10][
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(\[Theta]\)]\)"/"eV"], 
   Subscript[Log, 10][
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(\[Gamma]\)]\)"/
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(GeV\), \(-1\)]\)"]}, 
 RotateLabel -> False, LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 15), Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Placed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html)

```
RegionPlot[
 {x^2 < y^3 + 1, y^2 < x^3 + 1},
 {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.15, 0.08}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If instead of [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) you want to label the regions then use:

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[{x^2 < y^3 + 1, y^2 < x^3 + 1}, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5},
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.25]}, {Yellow, Opacity[0.25]}}],
 Graphics[{
   Text[Style[
     ToString[x^2 < y^3 + 1, TraditionalForm],
     Bold, 16], {0, 3}],
   Text[Style[
     ToString[y^2 < x^3 + 1, TraditionalForm],
     Bold, 16], {3, 0}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You! But I need slightly another thing: precisely, I want $x^{2} < y^{3}+1$ to be located on the blue domain, while $y^{2} < x^{3} +1$ to be located on the yellow domain. Independently on precise domain.

Comment: Add `PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.25]}, {Yellow, Opacity[0.25]}}`. When asking questions include your code and any constraints.

Comment: But does this move the "$x^{2} < y^{3}+1$" legend on the blue domain?

Comment: I only have one region and still want to get the legend. I tried the following, but why the legend does not show up?
`RegionPlot[x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.15, 0.08}]]`

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu - For any plot function, if there is a single expression to be plotted, `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` will not produce a legend. Try `RegionPlot[x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}, PlotLegends -> Placed[Style["x^2<y^3+1&&\ny^2<x^3+1", Bold], {.8, .8}]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks! Is it possible to still show the legend marker?

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu - Comments are not the place to ask new questions. Post a question with the code you have tried and explain what you want to do differently.

Comment: @BobHanlon Just created a new question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245464/regionplot-with-legend-marker

Answer (score 3):

```
Legended[RegionPlot[{x^2 < y^3 + 1, y^2 < x^3 + 1}, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}], 
 {Placed[SwatchLegend[{ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[1]]}, 
        {TraditionalForm[x^2 < y^3 + 1]}], {0.2, 0.7}], 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[{ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[2]]}, 
        {TraditionalForm[y^2 < x^3 + 1]}], {0.7, 0.2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]