# Regionplot with legend marker

Tags: plotting

I only have one region plot and still want to get the legend (both marker and label). I tried the following, but why the legend market does not show up?

`RegionPlot[x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5},   PlotLegends -> Placed["MyLegend", {0.15, 0.08}]]`

[image]

---

Edit:
Thanks @kglr for pointing out that {"MyLegend"} works in the original simple example. This helped me realize that what I want to achieve is slightly different. Since I use mesh to highlight the region, I was trying to get the legend for the mesh. Please see the code below:

`RegionPlot[x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, Mesh -> 12, MeshStyle -> {Hue[0.75], Opacity[0.3]}, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"MyLegend"}, {0.15, 0.15}]]`

[image]

Comment: try `PlotLegends -> Placed[{"MyLegend"}, {0.15, 0.08}]`?

Comment: `RegionPlot[x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[45, 1, 3], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["AllExpressions", {0.25, 0.8}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only reason for using `Mesh` is to get a hatch filling for the region, you can use [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html):

```
RegionPlot[x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Hue @ .75, Opacity @ .3, HatchFilling[Pi/4, 0, 10]], 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[{"MyLegend"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 30], {0.2, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

If you *have to* use `Mesh` + `MeshStyle` you can do

```
legendmarker = RegionPlot[True, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  Frame -> False, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, Mesh -> 7, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Hue[0.75], Opacity[0.3]], 
  PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];

RegionPlot[x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, Mesh -> 12, 
 MeshStyle -> {Hue[0.75], Opacity[0.3]}, PlotStyle -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[ {"MyLegend"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}, 
    LegendMarkers -> {legendmarker}], {0.2, 0.075}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The use of HatchFilling looks good. However, this command seems not recognized by my Mathematica 11.0. The color of this command is blue when I typed it, and the graph does not have parallel lines. So I guess this a version issue

Comment: I upgraded my software to 12.2 - now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
RegionPlot[x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1,
 {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[{x^2 < y^3 + 1 && y^2 < x^3 + 1}], {0.3, .07}]]
```

[image]